# How to dynamically invoke Junits

Tags: java, unit-testing, dynamic, junit, testcase

I have multiple instances of **junit.framework.TestCase** classes that contain various testcases. I want to write a program that runs particular testcases from these instances.

Is there a way to dynamically invoke junit tests, similar to the `invoke()` method from **java.lang.reflect** API?

Comment: Why don't you modularize your tests, then create a suite and runner for the specific tests you want?

Comment: Are you using Maven for your project?

Comment: @SubOptimal : No, I am using Ivy dependency management and Ant builder as the build tool.

Comment: @VinceEmigh : The tests are already modularized, but there are 100's of tests in each testSuite, and i am only required to check few tests from various suites. What i exactly want is a method that accepts a list of all the tests i wana run (From different testCases), and runs them.

Comment: @user2359572 I updated my answer with a link how to solve it with `ant` and `JUnit`. This might help you.

Comment: Why can't you create a new suite containing the specific cases you need to test, rather than create some method where you pass in your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not really clear what you want to achieve. Find below some more general possiblities. If you are using Maven you could

1. run specific tests

(for more examples/possiblities see [maven-surefire-plugin: single-test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html))

```
mvn -Dtest=YourClass* test
```

2. annotate classes for specific JUnit categories

(for more examples/possiblities see [maven-surefire-plugin: JUnit_Categories](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_JUnit_Categories))

```
mvn test -Dgroups="your.test.group.Example"
```

**edit** For `ivy` this SO post [how-to-run-all-junit-tests-in-a-category-suite-with-ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226026/how-to-run-all-junit-tests-in-a-category-suite-with-ant) might help to solve youre requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke your Junit using JUnitCore, it would be better if you run the whole test suite using Maven as @SubOptimal pointed out.

```
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    Result result = junit.run(CommonConstantsUnitTest.class);
```

Comment: But this way all the tests within the mentioned class will get run. I want to run only the ones i specify.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `@Category` Annotations
You can categories your tests and then invoke them which ever test using `@Category` or a combination of `@Category`