# Use @ExcludeCategory in ant

Tags: junit, ant

I want to exclude tests which have the @ExcludeCatory(Slow.class) annotation. 
But i dont find a the corresponding ant command. 
Something like `<exclude name="**/Slow.class"/>` does not work.

No, I don't think it's a duplicate.

I don't want to add another jar which contains the additional takari-cpsuite.jar 
into our system. I just want to use basic components junit and ant. And I also don't want to put TestSuites into our project with the references to the ignored files.

Comment: The answer is dependent on what test framework you're using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run all JUnit tests in a category/suite with Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226026/how-to-run-all-junit-tests-in-a-category-suite-with-ant)