# Not able to run all junit tests in a category with ant

Tags: java, testing, junit, ant

**Background**

I am trying to create an Ant script that:

- compiles source files
- compiles junit tests
- runs junit tests of a certain category

Most of what I have done so far, have been taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226026/how-to-run-all-junit-tests-in-a-category-suite-with-ant).

This is what I have in my ant script so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="junit_tests">
  <property name="build-main" location="build/main"/>
  <property name="build-test" location="build/main"/>
  <property name="src-test" value="java/test" />
  <property name="src-com" value="java/com" />
  <property name="src-lib" value="webapp/WEB-INF/lib" />
  <property name="test-lib" value="java/test/lib" />
  <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${src-lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${test-lib}" includes="*.jar" />
  </path>
  <path id="classpath.test">
    <path refid="classpath"/>
    <pathelement location="${build}"/>
  </path>
  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build-main}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build-test}" />
  </target>

  <target name="compileSrc" depends="init" description="compile src files ">
    <javac debug="on" destdir="${build-main}" encoding="UTF-8" fork="true" memorymaximumsize="1024m" includeantruntime="true">
      <src path="${src-com}" />
      <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </javac>
    <javac debug="on" destdir="${build-main}" encoding="UTF-8" fork="true" memorymaximumsize="1024m" includeantruntime="true">
      <src path="${src-test}" />
      <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </javac>
  </target>


  <!-- Test and build all files  -->
  <!-- To run this: use "ant" (default) or "ant run" -->
  <target name="run" depends="compileSrc">
    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="no" fork="true">
        <classpath>
          <path refid="classpath.test" />
          <pathelement location="${build-test}"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${build-main}" includes="**/NonDBTest.class" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
  </target>
</project>
```

**Output from junit task**

> run:
> [junit] WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit
> [junit]          jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7/libexec/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
> [junit]      and jar:file:/Users/arnab/work/my_project/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
> [junit] Running test.NonDBTest
> [junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.178 sec
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 37 seconds

**Problem**
The test class that is in this category `NonDBTest` has a total of 7 tests, so junit is clearly not running all of them.

`NonDBTest.java` is just a interface with no methods, and this is what my test class looks like

```java
@Category(NonDBTest.class)
public class MyTestClass extends AbstractTestCase{
....
    
    @Test
    public void testA(){ ... }
   
    @Test
    public void testB(){ ... }
   
    @Test
    public void testC(){ ... }
   
    @Test
    public void testD(){ ... }
   
    @Test
    public void testE(){ ... }

}
```

**Question**
What am I doing wrong? I have tried changing `NonTestDB` to a class. I've tried implementing the interface but nothing has worked so far. How can I get junit to run all classes that are in the `NonTestDB` category? Am I missing something?

Comment: I've added an answer to your linked [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42000110/1183010) which makes it possible to run tests of a specific `Category` via ant.

Answer (score 0):

Using JUnit categories is easier with `maven`, since you then can configure the categories to run via the [group](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/categories#using-categories-with-maven) attribute.

I doubt there is explicit support for categories in `ant`, and I don't think you can `include` a JUnit Category *interface* in the test task (as you seem to do).

The work around is to also create a JUnit *Suite* for your category, and then to only run that Suite from the ant target:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(NonDBTest.class)
@SuiteClasses( { MyTestClass1.class, MyTestClass2.class })
public class NonDBTestSuite {
  // will run only tests annotated with NonDBTest from
  // MyTestClass1 and MyTestClass2.
}
```

Then your ant configuration should indicate that the `NonDBTestSuite` should be executed.

```
<fileset dir="${build-main}" includes="**/NonDBTestSuite.class" />
```

Note that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6253061/165292) you are referring to also has this Suite defined.

The not so nice part of this is that you need to maintain all the suite classes. What I did with multiple categories is maintain one `AllTests` suite with *all* test classes. Smaller suites would then use this `AllTests` in the `SuiteClasses` annotation.