# How do I properly define a Suite test with Spring?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit4

So I have set my suite like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ 
    Foo1Test.class, 
    Foo2Test.class
    })
public class FooTest {

}
```

My unit tests are like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class Foo1Test {

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {/*...*/}
}
```

Everything is fine except when I run my project with `mvn clean install` the tests has been run twice. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: [Why are JUnit tests run twice from within Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720745/why-are-junit-tests-run-twice-from-within-eclipse)

I renamed my unit test as `*TestCase` and left the suite as `*Test`