# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, maven-3, junit4

I am using spring boot `1.5.14.release` version, eclipse IDE, Java 8, Windows 10.

This is the source code on my github:
https://github.com/codpra/spring-boot-tech

All test classes can be successfully executed in the IDE, and is executed in tandem, but some tests fail when I execute the maven command `package`. Why?

Extremely grateful.

The stack trace:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at cn.alittler.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl.update(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at cn.alittler.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75b82822.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at cn.alittler.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22ce978e.update(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at cn.alittler.web.rest.EmployeeRest.updateById(EmployeeRest.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at cn.alittler.web.rest.EmployeeRest$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$621e472.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:84) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at cn.alittler.web.filter.CustomizedAspect.handlerControllerMethod(CustomizedAspect.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at cn.alittler.web.rest.EmployeeRest$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d06312.updateById(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:160) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:151) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at cn.alittler.web.rest.EmployeeRestTest.test003UpdateById(EmployeeRestTest.java:85) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]`

Comment: You get this exception when the query returns no results, you must handle this exception in your DAO layer, can you share the stack trace.

Comment: Yes, I know that there is no result returned. But why the test classes can be executed successfully? because executed in tandem？

Comment: Are the other tests also failing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee employee = employeeRepository.findOne(id);
```

You should use `findOne` method when you are damn sure that it will return some result.

Alternative for this to use `findByXXX`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, it is caused by running test cases multiple times. These two links helped me：

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720745/why-are-junit-tests-run-twice-from-within-eclipse/34722465#34722465) and [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)