# How to specify @category in test task in gradle?

Tags: junit, gradle

I would like to learn whether I can specify the @category in gradle test task. So, [I can run separately integration junits and the normal junit tests](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0).

I know that there is currently [no explicit support for @category in gradle](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2111) and I am looking for a workaround for this limitation.

The straightforward approach is to define test suits for different test categories, e.g., [How to run all tests belonging to a certain Category in JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176570/how-to-run-all-tests-belonging-to-a-certain-category-in-junit-4). I would prefer to specify @category in my gradle script.

Comment: ps. It was much easier to put integration-test in a separate directory: src/integration-test/. This approach makes also the separation of the tests much easier to maintain and follow by team members.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Support for including or excluding categories has been included in gradle:

```
test {
  useJUnit {
    includeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryA'
    excludeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryB'
  }
}
```

Full documentation:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_grouping

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! I've used this approach for splitting Unit and Integration tests and also introduced a separate task to run Integration tests separately.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a solution other than implementing the feature or using test suites. Feel free to file a feature request at: http://forums.gradle.org