# gradle junit category additional testtask with different categories

Tags: java, gradle, junit, task, categories

Based on [How to specify @category in test task in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879527/how-to-specify-category-in-test-task-in-gradle)

I want to have 2 different test tasks:

- `test` for the fast tests
- `testLongRunning` for the fast and the slow tests.

I have successfully modified the buildin task `test` in a way that the "SlowTest"-s are onmitted:

`org.namespace.some.MySlowTestClass#someReallyLongRunningTest` is not executed as desired when executing task "test"

My question: Is it possible to add an additional gradle task "testLongRunning" that executes all tests (including `org.namespace.some.MySlowTestClass#someReallyLongRunningTest`) while the gradle task "test" does not excute the slow one?

My working example thas skips `SlowTest`looks like this:

---

```
// subproject/build.gradle   
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

test {
    useJUnit {
        excludeCategories 'org.junit.SlowTest' // userdefined interface in "subproject/src/test/java/org/junit/SlowTest.java"
    }
}
```

---

```
// subproject/src/test/java/org/junit/SlowTest.java
package org.junit;

// @Category see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872369/cannot-include-exclude-junit-tests-classes-by-category-using-gradle
public interface SlowTest {
 /* category marker for junit 
    via @Category(org.junit.SlowTest.class) */ 
}
```

---

```
// subproject/src/test/org/namespace/some/MySlowTestClass.java
package org.namespace.some;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.junit.experimental.categories.*;

public class MySlowTestClass {

    // @Category see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872369/cannot-include-exclude-junit-tests-classes-by-category-using-gradle
    @Category(org.junit.SlowTest.class)
    @Test
    public void someReallyLongRunningTest(){
    }
}
```

---

what i have tried:

when i add this to subproject/build.gradle

```
// this is line 65
task testLongRunning (type: test){
    dependsOn test
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'org.junit.SlowTest'
    }
}
```

i get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '...\subproject\build.gradle' line: 66

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':subproject'.
> org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your type might be incorrect. Try changing `(type: test)` to `(type: Test)`. I think `dependsOn test` is trying to us the `test` you're passing in as the type rather than seeing it as the actual task.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue. The following worked for me (similar to what Tim VanDoren suggested):

```
test {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'com.common.testing.UnitTest'
    }
}

task integrationTest (type: Test) { // Use 'Test' instead of 'test' here
    dependsOn test
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'com.common.testing.IntegrationTest'
    }
}
```